# Parsing xml - join split xml files into 1 pandas dataframe by file name in same directory

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I have 4-10 xml files in a folder, these files are broken down from a large single xml file. Luckily parsing the xml was easy because I could use `xmltodict` package. So I can do whatever I need to already with a single xml file. I converted it into pandas dataframe for analysis requirement. However, I need to combine 4 xml files into one pandas dataframe. Assume there is no data/ index issue, the files are surely correctly named as `00001.xml, 00002.xml, 00003.xml, 00004.xml` in order.

```
import xmltodict
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

with open('00001.xml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

def panda_maker (xml_dict):
    channel_list = xml_dict ['logs']['log']['logData']['mnemonicList'].split(",")
    logData_list = [i.split(",") for i in xml_dict ['logs']['log']['logData']['data']]
    logData_list.insert(0, xml_dict ['logs']['log']['logData']['unitList'].split(","))
    return pd.DataFrame(np.array(logData_list).reshape(len(logData_list),len(channel_list)), columns = channel_list)

logData_frame_01 = panda_maker(doc)
logData_frame_01.head() #all good
```

How can I neatly combine `logData_frame_01 + _02 + _03 + _04` to one dataframe?
Any further abstractions tips in above program is also highly welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
doc = []
for i in range(1,5):
    with open('0000{}.xml'.format(i)) as fd:
        doc.append(xmltodict.parse(fd.read()))

def panda_maker (xml_dict):
    logData_list = []
    for xmlval in xml_dict:
        channel_list = xmlval['logs']['log']['logData']['mnemonicList'].split(",")
        temp = [i.split(",") for i in xml_dict ['logs']['log']['logData']['data']]
        temp.insert(0, xml_dict ['logs']['log']['logData']['unitList'].split(","))
        logData_list.extend(temp)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.array(logData_list).reshape(len(logData_list),len(channel_list)), columns = channel_list)

logData_frame_01 = panda_maker(doc)
logData_frame_01.head() #all good
```

Comment: This works, in your `for` loop there are a few `xml_dict` that were changed to `xml_val` at my end, and it gave me required output. I will appreciate it if you can comment on how this kind of file of file reading problem is solved in real world.